# How to panTo a marker once a marker drops (Google Maps API)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to zoom into each marker on load once a marker drops onto the Google map.

I tried using the panTo and setZoom method inside the drop function and the addMarkerWithTimeout function, but it doesn't seem to work. I have spent the past couple hours trying to solve this issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
var neighbors = [
    {lat: 41.081445, lng: -81.519005},
    {lat: 42.652579, lng: -73.756232},
    {lat: 61.218056, lng: -149.900278},
    {lat: 32.735687, lng: -97.108066},
    ];


var markers = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemapsbackground'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795}
  });
}

window.onload = function drop() {
  clearMarkers();
  for (var j = 0; j < neighbors.length; j++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighbors[j], j * 1000);
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
    markers[j].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}
```

Comment: try adding `map.panTo(position);` once your added a new marker inside `setTimeout` function

Comment: I tried using map.panTo(position); but it didn't seem to work. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try utilizing a LatLngBounds object.

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    markers.push(marker);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }, timeout);
}
```